# Prime solutions to $x^2-2y^2=\pm 1$

Tags: number-theory, pell-type-equations

It is easy to see that if $(x_0,y_0)$ is a solution to $x^2-2y^2=\pm 1$, then so is $(x_i,y_i)=(3x_{i-1}+4y_{i-1},2x_{i-1}+3y_{i-1})$ (and with the same sign). A comment to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3103984/27542) points out that if $x_0=41$ and $y_0=29$, then it appears that $x_i$ and $y_i$ are simultaneously prime for infinitely many $i$.

I don't see how to approach proving this analytically. Of course, the statement is false if either $x_0$ or $y_0$ is $3$ - but is it true for every other pair of distinct odd primes $x_0$ and $y_0$?

Comment: Note:  if $x^2-2y^2=\color{red}+1$, then $y$ is even, so not prime if $y>2$

Comment: Related: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0606088.pdf, which I think shows that $3x+4y$ and $2x+3y$ are simultaneously prime for infinitely many pairs $(x,y)$.

Comment: @rogerl That's the proof of the Green-Tao Theorem! :)

Comment: @MrPie Yes it is. So most likely what I'm asking is nontrivial :)

Answer (score 3):

One way to look at the problem is that the $k^{th}$ solution to $x_k^2-2y_k^2=\pm1$ is
$$x_k+\sqrt2y_k=\left(1+\sqrt2\right)^k$$
Then
$$\begin{align}x_{(2j+1)k}+\sqrt2y_{(2j+1)k}&=\left(x_k+\sqrt2y_k\right)^{2j+1}\\
&=x_k^{2j+1}+\left(stuff+\sqrt2\cdot nonsense\right)\times x_k*y_k+\sqrt2\cdot2^jy_k^{2j+1}\end{align}$$
Since both $stuff$ and $nonsense$ are integers we can see that both $x_k|x_{(2j+1)k}$ and $y_k|y_{(2j+1)k}$. Since even powers have already been handled in this discussion it follows that we need only analyze $p^{th}$ solutions for odd primes $p$. A little testing with WolframAlpha shows that $x_p$ is prime for $p\in\{3,5,11,13,29,41,59,163\}$ and $y_q$ is prime for $q\in\{3,5,7,19,29,47,53,59,89,97,101\}$ for primes up to $163$, but it timed out factoring $x_{157}$ and $y_{163}$.

**EDIT**: @rogerl was kind enough to correct and expand my lists in a comment, so a complete list for $p<5000$ and $q<5000$ is $x_p$ is prime for $p\in\{3,5,7,19,29,47,59,163,257,421,937,947,1493,1901\}$ and $y_q$ is prime for $q\in\{3,5,11,13,29,41,53,59,89,97,101,167,181,191,523,929,1217,1301,1361,2087,2273,2393\}$. As can be seen, I was often copying from the wrong list above. Also he pointed out that $(x_p,y_p)$ is never jointly prime for $5000<p<10000$.

As a crude estimate, the $n^{th}$ prime is about $n\ln n$, so both $x_{p_n}$ and $y_{p_n}$ are about $\rho^{n\ln n}$ where $\rho=1+\sqrt2$ so the probability of numbers of that magnitude being prime is about
$$P(n)\approx\frac1{\ln\left(\rho^{n\ln n}\right)}=\frac1{n\ln n\ln\rho}$$
Since
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac1{n\ln n}$$
diverges and
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac1{\left(n\ln n\right)^2}$$
converges, it seems likely that there are infinitely many prime $x_p$ and also $y_q$ but maybe only finitely many jointly prime $\left(x_p,y_p\right)$.

**EDIT**: Of course the above discussion may be inaccurate because there are restrictions on the divisors fo $x_p$ and $y_p$.
If $q|x_p$, then
$$x_p^2-2y_p^2\equiv-2y_p^2\equiv-1\pmod q$$
So $2\equiv\left(y_p^{-1}\right)^2\equiv g^2\pmod q$ so that first of all, $q\equiv\pm1\pmod8$ and also since
$$x_p=\frac{\left(1+\sqrt2\right)^p+\left(1-\sqrt2\right)^p}2$$
It follows that
$$2(1+g)^p\frac{(1+g)^p+(1-g)^p}2\equiv(1+g)^{2p}+(-1)^p\equiv(1+g)^{2p}-1\equiv0\pmod q$$
So the order $2p$ (or $p$) of the element $(1+g)$ divides the order $q-1$ of the group $\mathbb{Z}_q^*$ so $q\equiv1\pmod p$ and only $2$ out of the $4(p-1)$ congruence classes $\pmod{8p}$ contain potential divisors of $x_p$.

If $q|y_p$, then
$$x_p^2-2y_p^2\equiv x_p^2\equiv-1\pmod q$$
So $q\equiv1\pmod4$.
If $2$ is a quadratic residue $\pmod q$ then $q\equiv1\pmod8$ and let $2\equiv g^2\pmod q$. Since
$$y_p=\frac{(1+\sqrt2)^p-(1-\sqrt2)^p}{2\sqrt2}$$
It follows that
$$2g(1+g)^p\frac{(1+g)^p-(1-g)^p}{2g}\equiv(1+g)^{2p}-(-1)^p\equiv(1+g)^{2p}+1\pmod q$$
And now the order $4p$ of the element $(1+g)$ divides the order $q-1$ of the group $\mathbb{Z}_q^*$ so $q\equiv1\pmod p$.
If $2$ is a quadratic nonresidue $\pmod q$ then $q\equiv5\pmod8$ and we make a field extension $\mathbb{Z}_q(g)$ where $g^2=2$ in our extended field. Then in the arithmetic of our field,
$$2g(1+g)^p\frac{(1+g)^p-(1-g)^p}{2g}=(1+g)^{2p}-(-1)^p=(1+g)^{2p}+1=0$$
So
$$(1+g)^{2p}=-1\in\mathbb{Z}_q^*$$
So the order of the element $(1+g)$ in the factor group $\mathbb{Z}_q(g)^*/\mathbb{Z}_q^*$ is $2p$ (or $p$) while the order of the factor group quoted is $(q^2-1)/(q-1)=q+1$, so $p|(q+1)$ and we have $q\equiv-1\pmod p$. Thus again only $2$ congruence classes are available: $q\equiv1\pmod{8p}$ and $q\equiv6p^2-1\pmod{8p}$ out of $4(p-1)$.

**EDIT**: A consequence for  [the referenced question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3103932/316404) of the solution $p=59$ is that if $n=19175002942688032928599^2$ then $n(n+1)/2$ has exactly $9$ divisors.

**PS**: My WA-fu isn't good enough to efficiently generate a longer list of the primes $p$ and $q$ so if anyone wants to add to the lists in a comment or simply edit it in, that would be nice.

Comment: +1. Using Mathematica, I get that $x_p$ is prime for $p\in\{3,5,7,19,29,47,59,163,257,421,937,947,1493,1901\}$ and $y_q$ is prime for $q\in\{3,5,11,13,29,41,53,59,89,97,101,167,181,191,523,929,1217,1301,1361,2087,2273,2393\}$, testing for primes under $5000$ (note that I think your list in the post is not quite right; for example, $x_7=239$ is prime).

Comment: For primes under 10000, the only times $x_p$ and $y_p$ are jointly prime are for $p=3, 5, 29, 59$.

Comment: @rogerl Thanks, I have edited your corrections and extensions into my answer.